# Drawing a color map with Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a color map like this: http://www.ritsplasman.com/images/colormap.png

I know Core Graphics has two functions that deal with gradients: `CGContextDrawLinearGradient` and `CGContextDrawRadialGradient`. A radial gradient is not what I want so I guess I'm forced to use the other one. But I cannot accomplish the example image using just a linear gradient.

The color map is basically a gradient where the hue changes horizontally and saturation vertically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name implies, the linear gradient only goes on one axis. In theory you could stack multiple gradients on top of one another to create a similar effect as that image but I doubt that would be a very efficient solution to the problem. I needed a similar color map in one of my iOS apps, I ended up using the image because it was far more efficient then trying to recreate it.

Comment: It should be possible to draw the gradient once using Core Graphics, then save it as a .png that I can use in my app, that way it's still efficient. I just need a way to draw it using CG so I can slightly modify it to my own wishes.

Comment: You can draw to a bitmap context and then save that as a PNG file.

Comment: Yes, I already know how to draw to a bitmap context and save it as a file, but I have no idea how to actually draw the color map. The "stacking multiple gradients on top of another" idea makes sense to me but I don't really know how to implement that stuff.. (drawing using hue, saturation, etc.)

Comment: You will need to do all the drawing in rgb so you will have to do a conversion for each of the HSV values. You will setup your linear gradient for all the colors along the x-axis using CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents and then draw that with CGContextDrawLinearGradient then move down the y-axis and create the next gradient for the second 'row' in the image. This is going to be a tricky process but hopefully this gives you enough to figure out how to get started.